# vsts-sync-migrator: Migration excluding build links

Tags: vsts-sync-migrator, azure-devops-migration-tools

I migrate the project from Azure DevOps to Azure DevOps using [azure-devops-migration-tools](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools) tool v8.9.2.

Is it possible to not migrate the build links?

See the screenshot bellow what I mean *build links*.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not posible to migrate the build history it is not posible to migrate build links. It would probably be better if those links were not migrated at all to prevent the red.

UPDATE: [petr-felzmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209459/petr-felzmann) has submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/pull/496) to remove build links when migrating which was integrated into v8.9.4+

Comment: Yes, my question is how to *not* migrate them. From your answer I understand it is not supported yet and it is candidate for the product enhancement ;)

Comment: It is not a thing that we can do, there is no API in Azure DevOps that would allow us to do this.

Comment: I understand there is no API to migrate the builds.But after I migrate a work item it contains also the original links to original builds. So I wanted to not migrate those links. Other solution can be to use API and remove the links from migrated work item after the migration is done.

Comment: You could submit a pull request to the GitHub project

Comment: Yes, your last comment is actually the answer to my original question, i.e. the product does not support it yet and it is matter of enhancement (where product is `azure-devops-migration-tools`). Thank you.